# Is there a way to get Dns.GetHostEntry() to be forced to use TCP instead of UDP in C Sharp?

Tags: c#, tcp, dns

Testing the Dns.GetHostEntry() with wireshark it seems that it uses UDP, which makes sense as the response is less than 512 bytes.
I understand that it falls back to TCP if the response is greater than 512 bytes but I was wondering if there was a way to make it use TCP even if it is less than 512 bytes as I want to test resolutions over TCP?

Comment: You may want to look at source (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/DNS.cs,eb768b1333d21612).  I not sure but I do not think the initial call is UDP/TCP.  It is the DNS protocol.  So what ever the RFC specified for DNS protocol is used.  The DNS is probably calling TCP/UDP.  I would have to do research and read the DNS RFC to be sure.

Comment: It like you can.  See sample code : https://dnsclient.michaco.net/  You can use option like : var result = client.ResolveServiceAsync("example.com", "ldap", System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp);

Comment: See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System  DNS is an application class that uses TCP or UDP.  There is a class property that you can set.  The C# Net library is managed and Microsoft has limited the parameter you can set in the IP header.  So in c# it make thing difficult to change IP message properties.  So either you could write a c++ wrapper.   Or use the windows dll ws2_32.dll.  See pinvoke for more details : https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ws2_32.send